# SQL поиск с помощью LIKE без учета скобок

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

У меня есть база иероглифов. Состоит из полей kanji (сам иероглиф), meaning (значение), on (китайское чтение), kun (японское чтение). Пытаюсь реализовать поиск по полям on и kun. В этих полях содержатся строки как эта: "や（く）、や（き）、や（ける）、く（べる）"  или эта "かず、かぞ（える）、しばしば、せ（める）、わずらわ（しい）".

Допустим я хочу найти иероглифы, которые читаются как やける, но не все иероглифы в базе в полях on и kun содержат подстроку やける, некоторые, например содержат や（ける）. Мне заранее не известно, где именно ставить скобки, если, например, подставлять их в PHP. Также не хотелось бы вносить изменения в базу.

Есть ли возможность реализовать поиск с помощью LIKE не учитывая скобки? Или имеется ли возможность вообще реализовать это средствами SQL?

Comment: *Есть ли возможность реализовать поиск с помощью LIKE не учитывая скобки?* Конечно. Их надо просто удалить перед поиском - REPLACE() в помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реализовать можно путем нормализации значения.
Для поиска やける без учета скобок:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE REGEXP_REPLACE(kun, '[\\(\\)]', '') = 'やける'
```

Для того, чтобы на большом объеме поиск работал быстро, т.е. использовался индекс, нужно его создать приблизительно так:

```
CREATE INDEX mytable_kun_normalized_idx
  on mytable ((REGEXP_REPLACE(kun, '[\\(\\)]', '')));
```

Comment: Использовал ваш вариант, получился вот такой запрос: `SELECT * FROM kanji WHERE kanji = "やける" OR REGEXP_REPLACE(onyomi, '[\\（\\）]', '') LIKE '%やける%' OR REGEXP_REPLACE(kunyomi, '[\\（\\）]', '') LIKE '%やける%'`, который выдает мне следующее: [ссылка на изображение](https://lukin.site/20200516101341.png). Как видно, у второго кандзи нет таких чтений. Мне кажется, он нашел похожее сочетание символов:"ひしゃ（げる）", но здесь маленький ゃ и げ, вместо や и け. Не подскажете, почему это происходит и как избавиться от лишнего результата?

Comment: Сравнение строк в юникоде - это тема для отдельного вопроса (возможно уже заданного). Не стоит обсуждать в комментариях, да и места для ответа тут не хватит.

Answer (score 1):

Почему бы не удалить скобки. `Relpace(Relpace(source, '(', ''), ')', '') like '%' + Relpace(Relpace(searchingString, '(', ''), ')', '') + '%'`